# Which Queue keeps a copy of the Object instead of just Reference?

Tags: c#, queue

I am currently using  System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection, and it´s very good with what it´s doing.

However it seems that it only keeps the reference of an object.

So if i have one byte[] object, which is written to and added to the Queue 100 times.

And after it reaches 100, i want to read all those, i will only get 100 copies of the current data "byte[]" holds.

Hope that explains it, at least it seems it´s doing this from my tests.

So if it´s doing this, is there another one that can keep copies of the data and just add it and add it till i read it?

Like for example, i would have 100 byte[] files, write it to a MemoryStream in the correct order, then i can read them in that order.

Though a Memory Stream isn´t what i would prefer to use, but works as an example.

Here is my code:

```
        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            for (int i = Queue.Count; i <= Queue.Count; i++)
                if (Queue.TryTake(out AudioData, 300))
                {
                    if (Record)
                        waveWriter.Write(AudioData, 0, AudioData.Length);

                }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e is ArgumentNullException)
                return;
        }
```

Here is the part which receives the data

```
            using (ms = new MemoryStream(TcpSize))
            using (var tt1 = tcplisten.AcceptTcpClient())
            {
                ReceiveData = new byte[TcpSize];
                tt1.NoDelay = true;
                using (var tcpstream = tt1.GetStream())
                    while (connect)
                    {
                        if (Record)
                            Queue.Add(ReceiveData);
                        tcpstream.Read(ReceiveData, 0, TcpSize);
                        waveProvider.AddSamples(ReceiveData, 0, TcpSize);

                    }
            }
```

You may wonder why i use a for loop and all that for writing, but it´s just there for debug purposes. I wanted to test if the objects in the Queue was copies, cause if so, it shouldn´t matter when i write it, but it does which means it must be reference.

Thanks

Comment: If you're using struct types (or builtin base types such as byte, int or double), you _will_ get value semantics. So your code will write the actual data, not any references.

Comment: From what I can see, you are always adding `byte[] ReceiveData` to the queue before you put any data in it

Comment: Actually, he's adding the _reference_ to a byte[] array to the queue, so this technically works (apart from possible threading issues), but he should move the `new byte[]` call inside the inner loop.

Comment: @PMF I seem to be suffering from code blindness. I didn't even notice the loop!

Comment: Regardless of using a loop, if `Record` is true the first time through it will add an empty array to the queue on the first iteration.

Comment: So i am using references, is what Matthew says below the solution?
Do i need to Clone it, or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Very true about the position of the ".Add", i moved it around while debugging, normally it´s at the bottom there so no worries:)

Comment: @Zerowalker You will need to either clone the buffer, or you will need to create a new buffer at the start of each iteration of the loop and use that instead (then cloning won't be necessary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to queue copies of the data, just make a copy and then queue the copy.

```
Queue.Add((byte[])ReceiveData.Clone());
```

But I think you also need to sort out the fact that you're writing the data to the queue before filling the buffer...

Alternatively, create a new buffer on each iteration and queue that instead:

```
while (connect)
{
    ReceiveData = new byte[TcpSize];

    tcpstream.Read(ReceiveData, 0, TcpSize);
    waveProvider.AddSamples(ReceiveData, 0, TcpSize);

    if (Record)
        Queue.Add(ReceiveData);
}
```

Comment: Wait so if i make a new ReceiveData, it means the old ReceiveData(in the Queue) is left? I thought it would "Clear" anything that used that reference.

Comment: @Zerowalker If you have put a copy of a reference to ReceiveData somewhere else (for example, into an array or a Queue) then it won't be garbage collected (cleared), because something can access it. The only time something is garbage collected is there are no "live" references to it reachable by any route. If the *only* reference to ReceiveData is in the Queue, and if you then remove it from the Queue (and don't keep hold of the reference you removed from the queue) *then* it will be garbage collected at some point afterwards.

Comment: Ah that explains it, so if i just keep on making new ones they will go away, But if i add them in the Queue they are "Alive".
But which is best performance wise, .Clone or "New reference" ?

Comment: @Zerowalker There's probably little in it, but just creating a new array on each loop is likely to be most performant - but more importantly, it's easier to follow.

Comment: I will go with the new Array, as you say it´s much easier to follow, and hopefully it´s a better performer or equal.

Thanks!